# How to solve "The table does not have the specified index" problem in AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I use AWS AppSync to create a learning management system. Amplify version is 12.3.0.
I tried to use a phoResultsByUserIdAndCreatedAt query but I got this error.

**[Error]**

```
The table does not have the specified index: phoResultsByUserIdAndCreatedAt (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: FI38DQLTQEEV0KIPBPRFSU9JJVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
```

**[schema.graphql]**

```
type PhoResult @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, operations: [read, create, update, delete] }]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  userId: ID! @index(sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"])
  materialId: ID!
  material: PhoMaterial @hasOne(fields: ["materialId"])
  materialGroupId: ID @index(sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"])
  materialGroup: PhoMaterialGroup @hasOne(fields: ["materialGroupId"])
  category: String
  kind: String! # normal / own
  topic: String
  level: Int
  lesson: Int
  group: String
  sentence: String!
  ipaSentence: String!
  ipaSentenceResult: String!
  qualityScore: Float
  soundFile: String
  wordList: [WordScoreList]
  lgmScoreTotal: Float
  lgmScorePhone: Float
  lgmScoreFrequency: Float
  lgmScoreStress: Float
  favoriteFlg: Int
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

**[query]**

```
query MyQuery {
  phoResultsByUserIdAndCreatedAt(userId: "7328af1f-9aa3-4782-9326-a19f19c7b86d", createdAt: {ge: "2023-07-01"}) {
    items {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is probably to add the index to the DynamoDB table or to change the name of the index in your call to the name of an existing index.

The problem with services such as Amplify and AppSync is that they are opinionated. If you use their automatic creation of other services such as DynamoDB tables and indexes, they "decide" what to create and how to name them. Usually, it makes the creation of the application easier and faster as many of the details are hidden away from you. However, when you deviate from the happy path, change some of the details manually, it might cause issues like the one that you are facing.

You can decide to open the hood and start examining and modifying the details such as adding or renaming an index, or to restart the process through Amplify and AppSync with fewer or no changes that might cause the above deviation from the standards.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the query you are trying todo in your schema.graphql. The index should be availiable if you look it up in the dynamodb console. But cloudformation havn't created resolvers in aws app sync for your query.

To have this availiable, you need to modify the userId attribute to have that query availiable.

First, to ensure that you don't destroy your index (in case you have other dependencies on that index), go to the aws console, then open dynamodb and find your table. Go to to your global indexes and find the name your index (the one that is connected to the userId).

Then modify your schema like this:

```
type PhoResult @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, operations: [read, create, update, delete] }]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  userId: ID! @index(name: "YOUR_INDEX_NAME", queryField: "phoResultsByUserIdAndCreatedAt", sortKeyFields: ["createdAt"])
  ...
}
```

In the queryField option is where you specify the name of your query. In this case I gave it the same name as the query you was trying to execute.

Then run amplify push or similar to build your new backend.

I think this will fix your query.

Also. You don't need to add the @primaryKey attribute on your ID, amplify automaticly makes that field as your primary key (default). Use @primaryKey if you want to modify the behaviour to be something else than default.